# How do I group all my functions in Python into one function?

Tags: python

I am using the Turtles Module where I am creating a U.S. Flag. The user decides the size of the flag and with that size I will be using it to create the width and length.

I am trying to group/compress all of my subfunctions into one huge function so the user can simply type `Draw_USAFlag(t, w) ## T = turtle W = Size` and it will carry out the task of the 5 functions that I already have.

For example I have 2 subfunctions: `draw_rectangle(t, w)` and `draw_stripes (t, w) ;` I want to group these two subfunctions into one function that will be called `Draw_USAFlag(t, w)` where it will use the user inputted `size (w)` throughout all of the functions. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Make a new function called `draw_USAFlat(t,w):` that calls the two sub function?

Comment: You can include the sub functions inside `Draw_USAFlag` if you want..

Comment: Not just can ... should. You want your functions to be simple and single purpose. Draw usa flag should do the minimum to do exactly what it's suposed to do, so it consists of nothing but function calls to draw the stripes, draw the field, draw the stars. Done, easy to understand, no clutter.  Let those other functions handle their underlying details.

Comment: I'm having problems with that right now; for example I already have my subfunctions: def draw_rectangle(t, w) and def draw_stripes(t, w). I've put those under a function called draw_USAFlag(t, w) and now my subfunctions say local function draw_rectangle is not used and local function draw_stripes is not used.  What do I have to change for my subfunctions? I want it to use the same Turtle and same user inputted size throughout the entire program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, make a function that calls the others:

```
def draw_rectangle(t, w):
    # however you do this
    ...

def draw_rectangle(t, w):
    # however you do this
    ...

def Draw_USAFlag(t, w):
    draw_rectangle(t, w)
    draw_stripes(t, w)
```

This assumes they don't return anything, so whatever they do works by side-effects on some other object. If e.g. they return an image, this will need changing depending on the exact structure of your system.

Comment: Thank you so much David, this really helped! :)